# Como actualizar el valor de un atributo de un objeto ya creado en python

Tags: python, lista, poo

Tengo una duda, no sé como actualizar el valor de un objeto que ya creé, mi caso  es así:

```
eventos = [] #lista con objetos provenientes de una clase

def igualdad():
   atributos = comparacion(eventos)
   cosa = input("Escriba lo que busca del atributo: ")
   for objetos in atributos:
       if objetos == cosa:
          objetos += "X"

def comparación(eventos):
   atributos = []
   for objetos in eventos:
      atributos.append(objetos.atributo)
   return atributos

igualdad()
```

Es un ejemplo, basicamente que al encontrar una coincidencia, pueda añadirle un dato extra al objeto y que la lista se me actualice.

Y otro caso donde el atributo es una lista de listas, haga los for necesarios para acceder al valor que quiero, y si hay coincidencia, modificarlo.

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo para comprender el código: datos de entrada y que resultado esperas al terminar. Asi como está, el código nunca hace nada.

Comment: Para modificar un atributo de un objeto necesitas una referencia al objeto. Si por ejemplo el objeto es `o` y tiene un atributo `atributo` que es una cadena a la que quieres añadir una "X" la sintaxis es: `o.atributo += "X"`. El problema con tu código es que la función `comparacion()` (por cierto, mal nombre le has puesto) extrae los valores de los atributos y retorna una lista de cadenas. Pierdes así de qué objeto venía cada una y por eso no puedes modificarla luego.

Comment: @abulafia muchas gracias, pensé que la referencia al objeto no se perdía, tuve que hacer un código algo largo pero logré modificar los atributos.